# EDIFACT DESADV without a Supplier Qualifier in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, edifact

In case I am processing an inbound DESADV that has only the Receiver Qualifier ZZ:

UNB+UNOA:1+SUPPLIER-DESADV+OURCODE-UTOPIA4:ZZ+...

There is no Supplier Qualifier

How do I configure my Integration Account (Agreement or Partner) to support the lack of a Supplier Qualifier? Do I inject on before my Decode Action in the Logic App?

What are the techniques others are using around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working with the Edit As Json feature and then deleting the qualifier, so that in the Agreement my guestIdentity is:

```
'guestIdentity': {
```

'value': 'SUPPLIER-DESADV'
}

That is, I deleted the qualifier property. This was also the advice from Microsoft.